# Data Factory Continuous Integration Deployment - Issue with IR when AAD authentication with managed identity used

Tags: azure-data-factory

Question based on this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment#set-up-an-azure-pipelines-release

When I want to deploy to a data factory from an arm template built from my dev data factory environment, I have an issue with my IR that uses "AAD authentication with the managed identity for your ADF": indeed, in this case the catalogAdminUserName is set to null. Therefore, I get this error at deployment from my release pipeline:

> The provided value for the template parameter
>   'XXXX_properties_typeProperties_ssisProperties_catalogInfo_catalogAdminUserName'
>   at line '1' and column '4053' is not valid.'

Any idea about how to fix this issue ?

Thank you!

Comment: Additional error logs:

There was an error while overriding 'XXXX_properties_typeProperties_ssisProperties_catalogInfo_catalogAdminUserName' parameter because of 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0', make sure it follows JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)

There were errors in your deployment. Error code: InvalidTemplate.